# Error en c: relocation truncated to fit R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en c en el cual tengo dos librerías, vector.h y entero.h, esta segunda creada a partir de vector.h. En el main utilizo las funciones de la librería entero.h, pero tengo un warning que dice:

relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol

en todas las funciones que utilizo y el programa no compila. He revisado que estén incluídas las librerías en todas las cabezeras, y que todos los nombres de las funciones, así como los parámetros, estén correctos. ¿A qué se puede deber este error?

El código de las librerías es el siguiente:

```
//vector.h

typedef int TELEMENTO;

typedef void * vectorP; 

void crear(vectorP *v1,unsigned long int tam1);

void asignar(vectorP *v1,unsigned long int posicion, TELEMENTO valor);

void liberar(vectorP *v1);

TELEMENTO recuperar(vectorP v1, unsigned long int posicion);

unsigned long int tamanho(vectorP v1);
```

entero.h

```
#include "vector.h"

typedef void *entero;

void creaEnteroLargo(entero *v1, unsigned long int tam1, int signo);

void asignarEntero(entero *v1,unsigned long int posicion, TELEMENTO valor);

void liberarEntero(entero *v1);


TELEMENTO recuperarEntero(entero v1, unsigned long int posicion);

unsigned long int tamanhoEnt(entero v1);
```

Y en el entero.c, además de las funciones implementadas, tengo lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vector.h"


typedef struct {
     TELEMENTO *cifras;
     int signo;
     unsigned long int tam;
}STENTERO;
typedef STENTERO *entero;
```

El código de la función recuperaEntero es el siguiente:

```
TELEMENTO recuperarEntero(entero v1, unsigned long int posicion){

    if (posicion >= 0 && posicion < v1->tam)
    {
        return v1->cifras[posicion];
    }
    return 0;
```

}

El compilador que utilizo es gcc versión 5.4.0

Este error me lo daba el Netbeans en Windows, pero al compilar en Linux obtengo un error similar:

referencia a `recuperarEntero' sin definir

Y así con todas las funciones.
Para compilar uso un makefile con lo siguiente:

```
CC = gcc -Wall 

HEADER_FILES_DIR = ./headerFiles

INCLUDES = -I $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)

MAIN = ejecutable

SRCS = main.c entero.c vector.c

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

DEPS = $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)/entero.h $(HEADER_FILES_DIR)/vector.h

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLUDES)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías darnos más información o poner el código en tu pregunta?

Comment: Muestra el comando **exacto** con el que generas el ejecutable. Completo. Y la versión del compilador usado. Y busca cualquier posible *arreglo* estático que uses, e indica el tamaño. Algo del tipo `STENTERO arreglo[NUMERO]`.

Comment: No utilizo ningún array estático, tan solo argv[1] de la línea de comandos, el resto son todos arrays dinámicos.

Comment: Perfecto. ¿ Y la orden exacta con la que compilas ? `gcc ...`.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con más información... Espero que sirva de algo

Comment: Ese mensaje se puede deber a varios motivos; en tu caso, se refiere a tus archivos objeto; se que es una tontería, pero ... ¿ está definido el cuerpo de la función `recuperarEntero` ? También deberías probar a cambiar tu Makefile: coloca las dependencias exactas de cada `.o`, no uses la regla `%.o: %.c ...`.

Comment: Si, están todas definidas... Y probaré lo del makefile, gracias, aunque no creo que sea eso el origen del problema, ya que el Netbeans también me marcaba ese error

Comment: Ok. Si en Netbeans te marcaba lo mismo, está claro que el problema no es de ahí. ¿ Podrías mostrar el código de `recuperarEntero` ? La verdad es que estoy *perdido*, pero **me gustan** este tipo de preguntas.

Comment: Si, ya he editado la pregunta para mostrar el código.

Comment: En principio, descartamos nada en dicha función. Es un error de *enlazado*, y ahí no usas nada externo. *Curioso*. Me gustaría seguir, pero no se me ocurre nada. ¿ Puedes subir el proyecto completo a *github* o algún sitio similar ? Para hacer pruebas. *¡ Me ENCANTAN estas cosas !* :-D

Comment: El proyecto es muy pequeño, si quieres podría pasarte el código del resto de los archivos :) y bueno, muchas gracias por la ayuda de todas formas

Comment: Ok. ¿ Puedes pegarlo todo en la pregunta ? O pásate por el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).